# How to fetch the jenkins build number in my @afterSuite method

Tags: java, jenkins, automated-tests, testng, jenkins-build-flow

Every time I run a jenkins job, I basically want to fetch that jenkins build number and create a backup folder in my project workspace which has @afterSuite method .So my backUp folder name and the executed jenkins build number should match. The purpose to create a backup folder is to move a couple of log and report files.
I have seen a lot of answers for setting a customised jenkins build number from project code, that is not my ask. My ask is i want the currently executing jenkins build number

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current build number using **${env.BUILD_NUMBER}**

Simple pipeline example:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage ('Greeting'){
        steps {
            echo "Hello, The build number is: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Output:
[image]

All the [jenkins environment variables](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) can be accessible using ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} or ${env.BUILD_URL} etc etc